# Azure DSC with PowerShell 7

Tags: azure, dsc, powershell-core, powershell-7.0, data-gateway

I am trying to automate DataGateway in Azure and recently in powershell 7 were released library to manage it.
But the problem that Azure DSC working with Windows Powershell 5 and even if VM have installed powershell 7 it's not working.

Can someone suggest a proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

## Enabling the Execution Policy:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
```

## Installing the Latest Version of NuGet and PowerShellGet

```
Install-PackageProvider Nuget -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force | Out-Null
Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Force -AllowClobber
```

## Creating the Foo Folder

```
$LFHT = @ {
ItemType = 'Directory'
ErrorAction = 'SilentlyContinue'}


New - Item - Path C: \Foo@ LFHT | Out - Null
```

These commands use a PowerShell technique known as splatting.
for more information, you can type:

```
 Get-Help about _ splattin
```

## Downloading the PowerShell 7 Installation Script

```
Set-Location C:\Foo
$URI = "https://aka.ms/install-powershell.ps1"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI | 
Out-File -FilePath C:\Foo\Install-PowerShell.ps1
```

## Viewing Installation File Help Information

```
Get-Help -Name C:\Foo\Install-PowerShell.ps1
```

## Installing PowerShell 7

```
$EXTHT = @ {
UseMSI = $true
Quiet = $true
AddExplorerContextMenu = $true
EnablePSRemoting = $true}


C:\Foo\Install-PowerShell.ps1 @EXTHT
```

The installation script that downloads the PowerShell 7 MSI Installation package then runs this code silently.

the name of the executable program you run to bring up the PowerShell 7 console is pwsh.exe.

Another noticeable difference is that with PowerShell 7, there are no .PS1XML files.

## Examining the Installation Folder

```
Get-Childitem -Path $env:ProgramFiles\PowerShell\7 -Recurse |
Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum
```

## Viewing Module Folder Locations

```
 $I = 0
$env:PSModulePath -split ';' |  
Foreach-Object { 
"[{0:N0}]   {1}" -f $I++, $_}
```

## Viewing Profile File Locations:

Inside the ISE

```
$PROFILE |
Format-List -Property *Host* -Force
```

from Windows PowerShell Console

```
powershell -Command '$Profile|   Format-List -Property *Host*' -Force
```

## Starting PowerShell 7

Open pwsh.exe, and hit Enter to open a PowerShell 7 console.
After you open the PowerShell 7 console, verify the version by viewing the $PSVersionTable variable

```
$PSVersionTable
```

## Viewing New Locations for Module Folders

```
$ModFolders = $Env:PSModulePath -split ';'
$I = 0$
ModFolders | 
ForEach-Object {"[{0:N0}]   {1}" -f $I++, $_}
```

## Viewing New Locations for Profile Files

```
$PROFILE | Format-List -Property *Host* -Force
```